# Retain value/state of a variable for a particular id of a spout in storm

Tags: r, apache-storm

I have defined a single bolt that calculates certain threshold. The bolt is receiving data for several values of a field. Is it possible that I can retain the value/state of a variable for a particular value of field.

Suppose I have two set of tuple inputs s$tuple$input:

```
s$id = "21343254545454354343"            s$id="45645465645456561234"
s$tuple$input = ["ABC",2]                s$tuple$input= ["CDE",5]
```

Is it possible to retain the value of a variable like counter=5 for "ABC" and counter=9 for "CDE" and update them only when a tuple for corresponding id is received.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't played with Storm and R but hopefully the ideas will be similar to Java.

You have a few options for storing state:

- In worker memory (per bolt)
- External store (not within Storm)

What you choose depends on your requirements but lets assume you're just trying to count words and don't really care if a worker dies. For this, the implementation is simple. Just create a private variable in your bolt and keep track.

For example, lets say you have a counts variable:

```
Map<String, Integer> counts = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

Then, in your bolt's execute method you just check if you've gotten the word before and if so increment the count:

```
Integer count = counts.get(word);
if (count == null)
   count = 0;
count++;
counts.put(word, count);
```

Source: [WordCountBolt.java](https://github.com/kitmenke/storm-stlhug-demo/blob/master/src/main/java/com/kitmenke/storm/bolt/WordCountBolt.java)

You also want to consider how tuples flow to the workers. You probably don't want to use shuffle grouping anymore. Instead you want to do a **field grouping by ID** so that tuples with the same ID go to the same bolt.

Going forward you probably want something more durable (so if you lost a worker then you don't lose all your counts) so you'd probably store your counts in something like HBase.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. We were thinking of using the same technique like using a map or list in R but did not think of the worker dying situation. Will make sure this point is covered too.